# base_url() and site_url() not working in live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on codeigniter .i tried to call controller function in form action.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url("Welcome/InsertValue");?>" method="post" name="frm1"  >
```

this is perfectly working on local server.but in live server it's show `404 Page Not Found` error.

This is my controller function

```
function InsertValue(){

        $this->load->database();

            /*db(Insert)*/
        $this->load->model("get_db");

        $data = array(
        'p_name' => $this->input->post('pname'),
        'y_addr' => $this->input->post('addr'),
        'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
        'apartment' => $this->input->post('apartment'),
        'web_url' => $this->input->post('website'),
        'p_manage_qu' => $this->input->post('pcompany'),
        'country' => $this->input->post('country'), 
        'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
        'p_addr' => $this->input->post('paddr'),
        'zip' => $this->input->post('zip'),
        'contact' => $this->input->post('contact')
    );

        $this->get_db->insert1($data);
        /*echo "new row added";*/
        /*db(Insert)*/

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('supplier/property');
    }
```

Comment: Please check the casing (small/upper case) of 'Welcome/InsertValue'.

Comment: try `site_url("welcome/insertvalue")`

Comment: $this->load->helper('url'); - Ensure this has been done

Comment: what link you got at the url that shows 404 error

Comment: @ShaifulIslam it's show `404 Page Not Found` error

Comment: Look at your browser address bar and what URL you see there?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam `abcd.com/index.php/Welcome/InsertValue`

Comment: does this link `abcd.com/index.php/Welcome/` also says 404?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam yes same result. `404` error

Comment: @Tje123 could be an .htaccess file issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908220/codeigniter-website-404-error-htaccess

Comment: Hard o find the problem,you can provide your real link.@Tje123 if you access page with index.php it does not related with .htaccess

Comment: You've loaded the URL helper and set up the routes page, right?

Comment: @Tje123 please post your control/er code where you want to redirect your code?

Comment: @ChrisEvans i've load URL helper and setup routes page

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('url'); in application\config\autoload.php

Comment: @saty same result.`404`

Comment: okk try <?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Welcome/InsertValue

Comment: @saty same result dude. `404`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things working on localhost and not working on live linux hosts is 99% due to case of controller names , paths etc.

When you develop on Windows or MACs, they don't care about case. Linux does.

So if your Live Host is linux based...
Your welcome controller should be lower case in the URL.

As an aside: It's generally normal to use lowercase for naming methods ie insert_value or camel case insertValue. But that shouldn't be a show stopper - it's more a coding style convention. CI recommends lowercase using underscores for word separation ie insert_value.

```
<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/InsertValue
```

Where your Welcome Controller name in the URL is **welcome** (All Lowercase) and **NOT Welcome**.

Plus always LOOK at the generated Links etc in your Pages Source to make sure it looks ok! From your browser. That's usually a Right Mouse Click - View Source (dependant upon the browswer you are using ). Or you can F11 and view the source in the Panel or Right Click Inspect Element... You need to know how to Look at what's being generated and to try things out when you get stuck.

Hope that helps.